# Error in PHP MySql codes when repeating similar scenario

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing problems with my PHP MySql codes when repeating similar scenarios, it can get a little confusing so i'll add some screenshots along the way to help.

So currently I'm in the middle of working on a drop-down list search engine which can be seen below. [image: Advanced Search Engine]

I have to get this search engine to work independently, despite having empty fields, which means that users can choose to either fill up all 3 fields, 2 fields or only one. I got the main code down, to display videos accordingly to this search engine. However, I am facing an issue where I am unable to display videos when only the "Program Level" field is indicated. Surprisingly enough, the code works for when only the "Course" or "Subject" field is indicated.

```
//Both Program and Course fields are empty.
elseif ($subject != '0' || ($program && $course == '0')){
        echo"program and course is 0";

        $advancedquery = "
        SELECT * FROM video INNER JOIN videosubjects
        on video.videoID = videosubjects.videoID
        WHERE subjectID LIKE $subject";

$runadvancedquery = mysql_query($advancedquery);
$foundadvancednum = mysql_num_rows($runadvancedquery);
    // echo "<b><p align = 'right'> $foundadvancednum videos are found!</b></p>";
    while($runadvancedrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($runadvancedquery)){
        $videoID = $runadvancedrows['videoID'];
        $thumbnail = $runadvancedrows['thumbnail'];
        $title = $runadvancedrows['title'];
        $description = $runadvancedrows['description'];
        $embed_url = $runadvancedrows['embed_URL'];
        $subjectID = $runadvancedrows['subjectID'];

        echo "<div class='container bottom space'>";


        echo "<div class='col-md-3'>";
        echo "<a href='video-page.php?vid_id=$videoID'> <img class='img1' src='../thumbnail-pictures/$thumbnail' alt='' width='350px' height='200px'> </a>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";

        echo "<a href='video-page.php?vid_id=$videoID'><h4 class = 'searchtitle'><b>$title</b></h4></a>";
        echo "$description <br>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

The above code is for when only the "Subject" field is indicated and it works fine. I mainly changed the elseif() condition and the query for different scenarios, also changed the variables accordingly. I only can't get it to work when users only indicate the "Program Level" field. I currently am using `elseif ($course && $subject == '0' || ($program != '0'))` and `$advancedquery = SELECT * FROM video INNER JOIN videoprograms on video.videoID = videoprograms.videoID WHERE programID LIKE $program` with everything else being the same. Thankful for any help given!

Comment: Is this a really old project that you have taken over from someone else? The `mysql_` functions are not supposed to be used!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to debug your code and `print_r` $subject,$program,$course and `die();` So,cross check weather its going in elseif() or bypass the condition actually.

Comment: I did add a message to be echoed for every combination, so i can tell that the code is bypassing the condition, and moving into another elseif() statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ifelse

```
(($course && $subject == '0') || ($program != '0'))
```

Working fine for me and it is going in elseif condition;

Comment: no this is still not working, still facing the same problem